# ¿Cómo utilizar un concat o un json?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-tool-suite

**Descripción del problema**

Tengo un problema donde necesito enviar mas de un dato a una columna a mi base de datos pero para eso necesito usar ya sea **JSON** o **concatenar** los datos que mando pero como soy nuevo en java y usando spring y no se como hacer eso, he visto algunas formas pero no los entiendo.

**Imagen del loop**

[image: Asi se ve el loop]

**Codigo que contiene el loop**

```
    <div class="divD">
        <h5 style="margin-right: 450px;">codigo</h5>
        <select
            style="width: 150px; margin-right: 450px; text-align: center;"
            class="select" name="origenP[]" id="origenP" multiple="multiple"
            size="10">
            <c:forEach var="participante" items="${participantes}">
                <option value="<c:out value="${participante.nombre}"/>">
                    <c:out value="${participante.nombre}" />
                </option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="divB" style="margin-top: -130px;">
        <input class="pasarP izq" value="Pasar »" type="button"> <input
            class="quitarP der" value="« Quitar" type="button"><br>
        <input class="pasartodosP izq" value="Todos »" type="button">
        <input class="quitartodosP der" value="« Todos" type="button">
    </div>

    <br>
    <div class="divA">
        <h5 style="margin-right: -450px; margin-top: -150px;">Equipo
            asignados</h5>
        <spring:bind path="RESA.codigoP">
            <select
                style="width: 150px; margin-right: -450px; text-align: center;"
                class="select" name="<c:out value="${status.expression}"/>"
                id="destinoP" multiple="multiple" size="10">
            </select>
        </spring:bind>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controlador**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/AgregarRESA.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String agregarRESA(ModelMap model) {
    RESA resa = new RESA();
    resa.setSala(new Sala());
    model.addAttribute(new RESA());
    this.cargarListaSalas(model);
    this.cargarListaParticipantes(model, null, Boolean.FALSE);
    this.cargarListaUsuarios(model);
    this.cargarListaResponsables(model);
    this.cargarListaEquipos(model);
    return "views/RESA/AgregarRESAForm";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/CrearRESA.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String crearRESA(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute RESA resa,
        BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) throws Exception {
    try {
        resaFormValidator.validate(resa, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            this.cargarListaSalas(model);
            this.cargarListaParticipantes(model, null, Boolean.FALSE);
            this.cargarListaUsuarios(model);
            this.cargarListaResponsables(model);
            this.cargarListaEquipos(model);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error");

            return "views/RESA/AgregarRESAForm";
        } else {
            status.setComplete();
            resa.setEstado("Activa");
            resaBo.incluir(resa);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "exito");

            return "redirect:ListarRESA.do";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: "Tengo un problema donde necesito enviar mas de un dato a una columna a mi base de datos" a que te refieres con mas de un dato? me imagino que es UN solo dato pero compuesto por mas de un campo? O como veo en la imagen, tu mandas 1 EQUIPO y ese equipo tiene varios miembros?

Comment: @sioesi        
Si exacto es un dato compuesto por mas de un campo ya que como puedo mandar un participante puedo mandar dos.

Answer (score 1):

Debe de haber solo un dato en cada columna de la DB, te recomiendo que la modifiques para que esté en 3ª forma normal.
Algo útil seria sería: guardar todos los datos que quisieras guardar en una misma columna en otra tabla diferente y apuntar a esta desde la "principal"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Específicamente con Spring no se como hacerlos pero generalmente cuando se hace un summit desde una pagina web con un multiselect el API de Servles lo toma como una lista o arreglo de strings, dicho esto creo que la propiedad RESA.codigoP debe de ser una arreglo de objeto que requieras, inténtalo de esta manera.

Answer (score 0):

No se mucho de Spring pero no necesitas concatenar o crear un json, desde el método del controlado puedes obtener los datos de tu formulario. Tienes que ver como funciona spring porque tiene unas notaciones en los cuales te permite hacer esto. Es similar a como hiciste para llenar la parte donde dice código pero a la inversa.